# How to deserialize different versions of the same bean class while the field structure of the bean class periodically changes?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

For example, I had a stable server running. It registered the server status on a zookeeper instance by serializing a `Status` instance in json format.

Some time later, I added a instance field to the `Status` class and started another `testserver` regitsering its server status on the same zookeeper instance.

Now I need to write some inspector program to monitor both servers. What should I do so that it deserializes both versions properly and hopefully handles future versions of `Status` class?

I tried to remove all fields and use a map instead. But it doesn't feel very convenient.
Like this:

```
public class Status
{
    private int serverId;
    //...
}

// changes to
public class Status
{
    public static final String SERVERID = "serverId";

    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    //... 
}
```

Any suggestions? Is there any best practice dealing with such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jackson to serialize and deserialize your classes, you can set [configurations](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) to ignore unknown or missing fields to allow the evolution of your Status bean :

- FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES
- FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES

This will allow the monitor to work with different versions of server Status JSON instances.